# Arc length of $(y-\sqrt[3]{x^2})^2+x^2 = 1$.

Tags: calculus, integration, arc-length

I am trying to compute arc length the area inside of closed curve $$\left(y-\sqrt[3]{x^2}\right)^2+x^2 = 1$$

It is known for the heart shape plotted at the end of the post.

I know how to compute the area using $$\int_{-1}^1 \left(\sqrt[3]{x^2} + \sqrt{1-x^2}\right) - \left(\sqrt[3]{x^2} - \sqrt{1-x^2}\right)dx = 2\int_{-1}^1\sqrt{1-x^2} = \pi$$

I found it superficially interesting because of the shape and the fact above that the area inside is just $\pi$. But I had a lot of trouble trying to compute the arc length of this curve:

$$\int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}-\frac{2x}{3\sqrt[3]{x^4}}\right)^2}dx + \int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}+\frac{2x}{3\sqrt[3]{x^4}}\right)^2}dx,$$ or $$\int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}-\frac{2}{3\sqrt[3]{x}}\right)^2}dx + \int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}+\frac{2}{3\sqrt[3]{x}}\right)^2}dx$$

How do I find the arc length of this curve?

[image]

Comment: wolfram alpha gives ≈3.95266 for half the curve

Comment: I doubt an integral like this would have a closed form. Seems like numeric methods are your best bet

Comment: Even the arc length of a non-circular ellipse eludes an elementary closed form. It would be interesting and surprising if this one has a closed form.